# Over a PID, every submodule of a free module is free

Tags: proof-verification, commutative-algebra, principal-ideal-domains, free-modules

> **Proposition** Let $R$ be a PID and let $F = F(X)$ be a free module
>   (generated by $X$).
>   Then every submodule $H$ of $F$ is free with
>   $$\operatorname{rk} H \leq \operatorname{rk} F = |X|.$$

I have seen the proof on page 640 of [Rot], where they use Zermelo principle (every set has a well order).
The same proof is poposed on [drexel28's blog](https://drexel28.wordpress.com/2011/11/21/submodules-of-free-modules-need-not-be-free-unless-ring-is-a-pid-pt-ii/).

The use of Zermelo principle bothers me because i'm used to use
maximality principles: Zorn's lemma or
[Hausdorff's maximality principle](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Hausdorff+maximal+principle).

Here i try to prove it using Hausdorff principle.
I would appreciate if you were to point out mistakes or give any comment.

---

- We know that a basis for $H$ cannot be extracted from $X$, consider for example $H = \langle (1, 1) \rangle$ in
  $R \oplus R = \langle (1, 0), (0, 1)\rangle$.
- Considering free submodules $\langle Y \rangle \subseteq H$ is a bit hopeless since it makes hard to control the rank of limit (union) bases.

This should motivate the choice of going from above. Consider the set

---

The following proof is nonsense.
I said: do not extract a subset from a basis, and then went doing it.

---

$$
S = \{Y \subseteq F : H \subseteq \langle Y \rangle \text{ and }
      Y \text{ is linearly independent}\}$$
ordered by inclusion.
The second condition in particular gives $|Y| \leq |X|$ since the rank
is well defined and monotone (passing to $F = A/m$-vector spaces).
If not, one could add this condition to the definition of $S$
without effort.

- Since $X \in S$, by Hausdorff there is a maximal chain $\{Y_{\alpha}\}$.
- This chain has a minimum given by $Y = \cap_{\alpha} Y_{\alpha}$.
  First note that the intersection $Y$ is in $S$:
  $$H \subseteq \cap_{\alpha} \langle Y_{\alpha}\rangle
        \subseteq \langle Y \rangle.$$
  The first inclusion is clear, we need to show the second one.
  Let $x \in \cap_{\alpha} \langle Y_{\alpha}\rangle$ and consider
  any two indices $\alpha, \beta$.
  Without loss of generality we can assume that
  $Y_{\alpha} \subseteq Y_{\beta}$ (since this is a chain). Then
  $$
    \begin{align}
    x
    &= r_1 \, y^{\alpha}_1 + \ldots + r_n \, y^{\alpha}_n \\
    &= s_1 \, y^{\beta}_i + \ldots + s_m \, y^{\beta}_m.
    \end{align}
    $$
  Since this identity is true in $\langle Y_{\beta} \rangle$,
  which is free, we must have $\{y^{\alpha}_i\} = \{y^{\beta}_j\}$.
  Since this is true for any choice of indices we have that
  $x \in \langle Y \rangle$.
  Finally, by maximality the chain contains $Y$.
- To conclude we need to show that $H \supseteq \langle Y \rangle$.
  Note that, so far, we have not made use of the fact that $A$ is a PID.
  in this step we are also going to use the minimality of $Y$.
  Suppose that
  $$\langle Y \rangle \ni x = r_1 y_1 + \ldots + r_n y_n$$
  with $y_i \in Y$ and assume that $x \not\in H$.
  Then there is an $y_i = y$ which is not in $H$.
  Set $Y' = Y \setminus \{y\}$. We claim that
  $$H \subseteq \langle Y' \rangle$$
  which gives a contraddiction on the minimality of $Y$.
  Since $R$ is a PID, by ($\ast$) we have that $r y \not\in H$
  for every $r \neq 0$.
  Let $h \in H \subseteq \langle Y \rangle$. Then
  $$h = r y + r_1 y_1 + \ldots + r_n y_n$$
  with $y_i \in Y'$. This gives $r y \in H$, hence $r = 0$
  and so $x \in \langle Y' \rangle$.

$\blacksquare$

(*) We have that $H \cap \langle y \rangle$ is a cyclic $R$-module,
    which is isomorphic either to $0$ or to $R$
    (the second case being impossible since $y \not\in H$).

---

[Rot] Joseph J. Rotman `Advanced modern algebra', GSM second edition, 2010.

Comment: Your own rank $2$ example shows that a minimal element of $S$ need not be a basis for $H$.

Comment: I see that now. One could start with $X$ being the pair in the example (in fact it is what i used to show that $S$ is non-empty) and then the proof would extract a subset from it, since the partial order is inclusion; also there is a mistake at the end, i said $ry \in H$ thinking that the $y_i$ where also in $H$, which is not the case. Thanks!